# How to match only IP Address from two files; but leaving a specific text intact in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two files; can considered it as columns; but I need to exctract only the one that has ip address. If in both files there is text file; then can leave that intact. I tried "join" and awk without success.. Here is the output and the desired output.

```
FILE1            FILE2               Desired Output (FILE 3)
192.168.217.36   d0:d3:e0:cb:dc:f4   192.168.217.36
192.168.229.70   20:4c:03:59:ed:6a   192.168.229.70
No_IP_Found      192.168.197.181     192.168.197.181
192.168.230.81   192.168.230.81      192.168.230.81
No_IP_Found      No_IP_Found         No_IP_Found
No_IP_Found      84:d4:7e:cf:5c:9c   No_IP_Found
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: What if they both have an IP like line 4 but they're different IPs? Which one should be in the output?

Comment: Read a line from each file into two variables. Check if either of the variables contains an IP, and write that to the output. If neither of them is an IP, write `No_IP_Found` to the output.

Comment: Use `paste` to combine both files, not `join`.

Comment: Hi Barmar; as for line 4; we will take always IP from FILE1. But that's its very hard to happen based on all parsing that I already performed before to extract both files. Yes, paste will makes both files into one; but how to get only that ipadrr?  I can use this grep to keep ip address and "No_IP_Found" .                                                            grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|No_IP_Found'

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste` because I'm lazy:

```bash
paste FILE1 FILE2 |
awk '
    {
         if (match($0,/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/))
             print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
         else
             print "No_IP_Found"
    }
'
```

```
192.168.217.36
192.168.229.70
192.168.197.181
192.168.230.81
No_IP_Found
No_IP_Found
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks... Can you explain the print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)?

Comment: `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set by the `match` function; `RSTART` is the starting position of the matched string and `RLENGTH` is its length.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- if both files contain an (ipv4) ip address then print the one from `file1`
- both files have the same number of lines
- all lines contain a single field (with no embedded spaces); otherwise we only process the first space delimited field

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { regex="([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" }            # define the (ipv4) ip address regex
FNR==NR { a[FNR]=$1; next }                               # 1st file: save field #1, skip to next input line
        {      if (a[FNR] ~ regex) print a[FNR]           # 2nd file: if 1st file had valid ip address then print it
          else if ($1     ~ regex) print $1               # else if 2nd file has valid ip address then print it
          else                     print "No_IP_Found"    # else print default
        }
' file1 file2
```

This generates:

```
192.168.217.36
192.168.229.70
192.168.197.181
192.168.230.81
No_IP_Found
No_IP_Found
```

Comment: Love it. Thanks a lot!!!!  This will also helps me for future as reference. Creating the regex then the logic!…

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{$1~/\./?$0=$1:($2~/\./?$0=$2:$0="NO_IP_Found")}1' <(paste FILE1 FILE2)
```

Assuming that you only have ip addresses, mac addresses and the string NO_IP_Found as text

```
awk '
    {
        $1 ~ /\./ ? $0 = $1 \                   # check if field 1 has any dot "."
                                                # if true assign $1 to $0
            :                                   # if false
            ( \
                $2 ~ /\./ ? $0 = $2 \           # check if field 2 has any dot "."
                                                # if true assign $2 to $0
                    : \                         # if false 
                    $0 = "NO_IP_Found" \        # assign "NO_IP_Found" to $0
            )
    }1                                          # print $0 after modifiying
' <(paste FILE1 FILE2)



# without assigning
$ awk '{print($1~/\./?$1:($2~/\./?$2:"NO_IP_Found"))}' <(paste FILE1 FILE2)
```

Comment: This is the simplest code; it also worked; but hardest for me to understand it. Can you explained me?

Comment: @JavierGonzalez Ola Javier, got the explanation in there. buena suerte!

Comment: Gracias ufopilot!! 

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about sorted order, here's a strange way to go it that filters out either ipv6 or MAC addresses but doesn't verify the ipv4 ones :

```
{m,g}awk '___[$_]++<(NF*=NF==!_) || (__==$_)==(FNR-___[__])' \
                                     __='No_IP_Found'  FS=':' file1 file2

192.168.217.36
192.168.229.70
No_IP_Found
192.168.230.81
192.168.197.181
No_IP_Found
```